# Array Member function on a literal

Tags: arrays, coldfusion, member-functions, coldfusion-11

This works

```
<cfif ArrayContains(["bridge","ccf"], getSection())>
```

This does not

```
<cfif ["bridge","ccf"].Contains(getSection())>
```

Error message

Column 7

> Detail ColdFusion was looking at the following text:
>
> [
>
> The
>   CFML compiler was processing:
>
> - A cfif tag beginning on line 15,
>     column 2.
>
> KnownColumn 2   KnownLine 15   KnownText cfif   Line
>   15   Message Invalid CFML construct found on line 15 at column 7.
>   Snippet

Did I convert this right, of is this a limitation of Adobe's implementation?

Comment: `ArrayContains()` works fine

Comment: (Edit) Then why do you need ["bridge","ccf"].Contains(getSection())?  :) I suspect you will have to use an intermediary variable. Though, I would not recommend using .Contains() as it is a java method, meaning it is case and type sensitive.  Side note, you are missing a closing `>` in the CFIF. Not sure if that is a typo.

Comment: It is just a code fragment. The rest of the code is OK. I am trying to convert my code to use member functions. I am thinking that ACF does not support a literal on a member function.

Comment: (Edit) Most likely not. You will need an intermediary variable. *it is case and type sensitive.* Never mind.  Bad testing on my part. I forgot ArrayContains *is* case sensitive too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ColdFusion does not support calling methods on a literal, no.

Ref: [Member functions cannot be called on literals](https://bugbase.adobe.com/index.cfm?event=bug&id=3712122), which says:

> This should work:
>
> `"lowercase".ucase()`
>
> It currently doesn't.

Comment: Coincidentally, guess what comes up as the first search result for "ColdFusion Array Member function on a literal"? ;-)  http://blog.adamcameron.me/2014/02/coldfusion-11-member-functions.html